# How to create unique index in Access w/ integer fields that may be null?

Tags: ms-access, indexing, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to create a unique multi-column index on a table in Access.  Several of the fields I'll be using in the index are long integers.  These fields may be blank in some records.  I know that I can't allow actual NULLs because then I can't have unique records, e.g. if I try to build the table as follows:

```
Field1 (text),Field2 (integer),Field3 (text)
1:"a",56,"c"
2:"x",NULL,"f"
3:"x",NULL,"f"
```

then row 3 will be allowed (which I don't want) because the NULLs aren't really "equal" to each other.

I saw a solution where they set the following in Design View:

```
"Required"="Yes"
"Allow Zero Length"="yes"
"Default value"=""
```

But that won't help here because integers can't be set to "".

So, any ideas on creating a unique index under these circumstances?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm goin on general DB theory, but Acess could break the mold.  Theory makes NULL fail to do as you wish because DBs take null to essentially mean "give up on evaluating".  This leaves you to set a default value, like 0, -1 or minimum int for example, but that leaves you with fake, meaningless data--a very bad thing.

Can you add a surrogate field (say of string type) that is populated with the string representation of your integer?  Not sure about Access, but triggers or calculated columns are two general DBMS options for doing this.

Comment: Thanks, I'm now using the surrogate field technique and it seems to be providing a satisfactory unique index.

Comment: But it still won't prevent insertion of the duplicate records. Use of a surrogate key does not excuse you from having a proper unique index on the "natural" key fields.

Comment: It's the implementation of the business rules that is failing to give meaning to a NULL value. If this integer was a FK to a lookup table, it would help if there was an entry of "Unknown". A 0/-1 false entry (numeric value/not a lookup) would interfere with calculations (AVG) unless you constantly enforce omitting this record.

Comment: And just to clarify, I meant "surrogate" in the English context of stand-in (allowing a nonsensical value that can be indexed) rather than the SQL context of a "surrogate key". I apologize for any confusion

Comment: I suspect there's a way to engineer away this problem with the schema, but since we don't know what entities are being represented, it's impossible to suggest anything. The idea is to convert fields into records, so that the lack of a record serves the purpose that the Null field previously served.